# Eliminate dups and sum corresponding terms in lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

Given these 2 lists

```
L2 = [A,B,C,D,A,B]
L3 = [3,2,1,2,2,1]
```

I want to obtain

```
L2_WANTED = [A,B,C,D]
L3_WANTED = [5,3,1,2]
```

The lists are always ordered and same size and elements correspond as key value pairs eg A:3, B:2 and so on.

The objective is to eliminate the dups in L2 and sum the corresponding terms in L3 to obtain a new list with matching pairs. This is to keep a running list of items as they are added to the lists.

I tried to write a function with `index` but it started to get ugly. I checked `itertools` but could not find anything that relates; I looked at `starmap()` but couldn't make it work. Probably this can be done with list comprehension as well. I would appreciate any clues or directions about how to achieve this most simple way. Thank you.

**EDİT**

@SimonC:

```
>>> l2_sum = {}
>>> for i in range(0, len(L2)):
        key = L2[i]
        num = L3[i]
        l2_sum[key] = l2_sum.get(key, 0) + num


>>> l2_sum
{'A': 5, 'C': 1, 'B': 3, 'D': 2}
>>>
```

How does this eliminate the dupes and add the numbers? Can you give a clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are more elegant answer there and would come in the replies.

But for some simple answers:

```
L2 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']
L3 = [3,2,1,2,2,1]

L4 = zip(L2, L3)

L5 = []
L6 = []
def freduce(l):
    for x, y in l:
        print x , y
        if x in L5:
            k = L5.index(x)
            L6[k] += y
        else:
            L5.append(x)
            L6.append(y)

freduce(L4)  
print L5
print L6
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
[5, 3, 1, 2]
```

[Edited answer for understanding the second implementation]

```
>>> L3 = [3,2,1,2,2,1]
>>> L2 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']
>>> range(0, len(L2))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

Hence in for i in range(0, len(L2)): ... i becomes an index

Using this index, you could extract information from L3 and L2 by doing:

```
key = L2[i]
num = L3[i]
```

Then you add information to the dict

```
l2_sum[key] = l2_sum.get(key, 0) + num
```

Here l2_sum.get(key, 0) returns 0 if the key is not present otherwise the current value.

I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: This looks elegant to me! Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm not trying to be inflammatory, but I think my answer is slightly clearer in it's intent.  Although maybe that's because I come from a more procedural background and functional programming makes my head hurt...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I agree. I just got a chance to look at it and I edited my question if you want to take a look.

Comment: @Zeynel: I have provided a verbose explanation.

Comment: I just saw this page about Google's `szl` language: http://code.google.com/p/szl/. The example they give is an answer about how to solve my question with `szl` language. I thought it was interesting.

Comment: @Zeynel: +1 Thanks a lot for the link. It piques my interest in finding it out. I was trying the dishes by Tate (seven languages in seven weeks).

Answer (score 2):

I think using `zip` is a nice way to combine the lists. The `dict.update` portion will do the summing since I fetch the previous value and update it:

```
foo = dict()
for x, y in zip(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B'],
                [3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]):
    foo[x] = y + foo.get(x, 0)

print foo
```

Outputs:
`{'A': 5, 'C': 1, 'B': 3, 'D': 2}`

Edit:

While the above is fine, I'd also consider using [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) which allows you to do the `zip` as you build the dictionary. This way you'll save on memory. All you'd need to do is replace `zip` with `itertools.izip` after importing `iterools`

Comment: nice and with a OrderedDict http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?#collections.OrderedDict you get the order too!

Comment: Totally! I think I'd consider using izip as well so you dont need to calculated the entire zip first.

Comment: thou `foo.update({x: y + foo.get(x, 0)})` is kind of wierd, `foo[x] = foo.get(x,0) + y` is straight forward.

Comment: Ah yes, and that's faster too... at least it has less bytecode operations. Here's proof: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/285810/

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, but as per pyfunc, there are better ways:

```
l2_sum = {}
for i in range(0,len(L2)):
    key = L2[i]
    num = L3[i]
    l2_sum[key] = l2_sum.get(key, 0) + num

L2_WANTED = sorted(l2_sum.keys())
L3_WANTED = [l2_sum[key] for key in L2_WANTED]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll look at this more carefully tomorrow but a quick try in IDLE gives an error: `
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` (it may be my mistake)

Comment: My definitions of L2 and L3 look like:


    L2 = ['A','B','C','D','A','B']
    L3 = [3,2,1,2,2,1]

Comment: Sorry, hitting enter seems to post the comment... I meant to add that you will need to change to 'num = int(L3[i])' if your L3 list contains strings.